# Building Thor SFML Extension with CMake Error

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

I am trying to build the The Thor SFML extension with the cmakeLists provided. The project configures, and generates, but when I run make, the build fails because it cannot find the include files. The actual message is below:

```
c:/Libs/Thor2.1/src/Action.cpp:26:33: fatal error: Thor/Input/Action.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <Thor/Input/Action.hpp>
                                 ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project.dir/Action.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have set the build dir as /lib

I'm not sure what would cause this with cmake. I am using the commit that is compatible with SFML-2.1. It is available on the Thor Library home page.

I checked and the file in question does exist.

Comment: Could You please clarify the way to recreate Your case?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, which step have You failed, but manually setting the  `SFML_ROOT` and `SFML_INCLUDE_DIR` while configuring the Thor library worked well for me. An example of doing that:

```
cmake -DSFML_ROOT=../../sfml/build/ -DSFML_INCLUDE_DIR=../../sfml/include ..
```

Full sequence of steps:

```
# acquire proper version of Thor: 
git clone git://github.com/Bromeon/Thor.git
git checkout f57666db6f187eb57bbc0947456cce2159a9b617

# acquire proper version of SFML:
git clone https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML.git
git checkout 2.1

# build SFML:
mkdir ./SFML/build
cd ./SFML/build
cmake ..
make
cd -

# build Thor:
mkdir ./Thor/build
cd ./Thor/build
cmake -DSFML_ROOT=../../SFML/build/ -DSFML_INCLUDE_DIR=../../SFML/include ..
make
```

Comment: I get these errors when trying to generate the makefiles:

Comment: I keep getting the same error, cmake can't seem to find the include path.

Comment: @Cayleus have You tried setting that `SFML_INCLUDE_DIR` path manually?